# maven is not run main class when run from command promt

Tags: java, maven-3

Hi i used maven to create a project. Basically i created project using eclipse. Then i build the project. Everything is running fine from eclipse. Now when i compile the project, then maven created a classes directory in target directory.

[image: Maven Target directory structure]

This directory contain all the class files. Now i when i move to my main file and run it from command prompt by

```
java BatchImport.class
```

Then i get the error that

```
could not find or load main class BatchImport.class.
```

How can i run it from command prompt?

here is my maven configuration

```
<build>

    <!-- to avoid maven-dependency-plugin (goals “copy-dependencies”, “unpack”) is not supported by m2e error -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Ignore/Execute plugin execution -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                         <pluginExecutions>

                            <!-- copy-dependency plugin -->
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

        <!-- Maven compiler plugin
             If you run the code maven package now, Maven will package this Java project into a jar file 
             named “LS360BatchImportIntegration-1.0.0.jar“, in target folder. 
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- To make jar file like a exe file, you need to define a manifest file and declare the application 
             entry point inside via maven-jar-plugin in pom.xml. 
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>

            <!-- The configuration of the plugin -->
            <configuration>

                <!-- Configuration of the archiver -->
                <archive>

                    <!-- Manifest specific configuration -->
                    <manifest>

                        <!-- Classpath is added to the manifest of the created jar file. -->
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>

                        <!--
                           Configures the classpath prefix. This configuration option is
                           used to specify that all needed libraries are found under dependency-jars/
                           directory.

                           Use “classpathPrefix” to specify folder name in which all properties will be placed.
                       -->
                        <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>

                        <!-- Specifies the main class of the application -->
                        <mainClass>pk.training.basitMahmood.BatchImport</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--  uses maven-dependency-plugin to copy all dependencies to "target/dependency-jars/" folder, and 
              defines the dependency classpath with maven-jar-plugin 
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeGroupIds>
                            log4j, org.slf4j, org.springframework, commons-net, commons-collections, 
                            org.apache.commons, javax.mail, org.apache.velocity, commons-logging
                        </includeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks

**Edit 
-----------------**

[image]

I tried it with BatchImport.class and just BatchImport but i am getting no main class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each class has a package declaration. You must run your class with

```
java my.pkg.MyClass
```

where "my.pkg" is the package name and "MyClass" is the class name.

And just to avoid future complications: You must run it from the directory, that is the parent of your package directories. In your case, it is the classes directory from your screenshot.

Comment: Then kindly check your screenshot, and please read again my answer.

Comment: This command is running `D:\Personal Work\eclipse 32 Bit\workspace\Spring Integration\LS360BatchImportIntegration\target\classes>java -cp ".;d:\dependency-jars\*"  com/softech/ls360/integration/BatchImport test`